# Getting error when using FOR OF array loop using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Here, Why my code is not working in IE.
My code is working for all browser.there is no issue.
But when I run my project on IE its find error.

And also my jquery class and insertadjacentHTMl not working.

main issue i find in this code.

```js
$("[type=slideshow] section").addClass('hide');
  for(let ele of Array.from($("[type=slideshow]"))){
   $(ele).children("section:first").removeClass("hide").addClass('active');
  }
```

Here, is my code please review it where is error .

```js
//Code for Slideshow

var divSlide = document.querySelectorAll('#slide');

var myNodeList = divSlide.length;
let slideNo = 1;

for(var i = 0; i < myNodeList; i++) {
 var type = divSlide[i].getAttribute("type");
 if (type == "timeline") {

 } else if (type == "slideshow") {
  var timeline = divSlide[i];     
  let sliderData = timeline.getElementsByTagName("section");
  
  $("[type=slideshow] section").addClass('hide');
  for(let ele of Array.from($("[type=slideshow]"))){
   $(ele).children("section:first").removeClass("hide").addClass('active');
  }

  timeline.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",'<a class="left prev color_arrow carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>');

  timeline.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<a class="right next color_arrows  carousel-control" href="#myCarousel"  data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>');
 }
}

$(document).on ('click','.prev',function() {
 let select = $(this).parent();
 let totChild = select.children("section");
 for(let i=0;i<totChild.length;i++){
  if(totChild[i].getAttribute('class').indexOf('active')!=-1){
   slideNo=i+1;
  }
 }
 totChild.children('br').remove();
 let current = select.children('.active');
 let prevEl = current.prev('section');
 
 if(slideNo === totChild.length || slideNo > 1){
  select.children(".next").show();
  if(prevEl.length !== 1){
   prevEl = current.prev().prev();
   current.removeClass('active');
   current.addClass('hide');

   prevEl.addClass('active');
   prevEl.addClass('animated');
   prevEl.addClass('fadeInLeft');
   prevEl.removeClass('hide');
  }
 } else {
  select.children(".prev").hide();
 }
});
$(document).on ('click','.next',function() {
 let select = $(this).parent();
 let totChild = select.children("section");
 for(let i=0;i<totChild.length;i++){
  if(totChild[i].getAttribute('class').indexOf('active')!=-1){
   slideNo=i+1;
  }
 }
 
 totChild.children('br').remove();
 let current = select.children('.active');
 let prevEl = current.next('section');
 if(slideNo ===1 || slideNo < totChild.length){
  
  select.children(".prev").show();
  if(prevEl.length !== 1){
   prevEl = current.next().next();
   current.removeClass('active');
   current.addClass('hide');
   prevEl.addClass('animated');
   prevEl.addClass('fadeInRight');
   prevEl.addClass('active');
   prevEl.removeClass('hide');
  }
 } else {
  select.children(".next").hide();
 }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the error on IE?

Comment: : Expected ';'  this is show in console.log

Comment: That's because `for..of` is completely unsupported in IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Why not iterate `$("[type=slideshow]")` using jquery's `each`?

Comment: @gurvinder372  because i have 4 div everything same except it type= timeline and slidehsow and i loop over all section inside div or type div. so i use each $("[type=slideshow]"). give me some suggestion gurvinder pajji.

Comment: Please share a working snippet that demonstrate your issue. Unless we see rest of your markup (including markup), it is almost impossible to give a concrete suggestion without seeing your issue getting replicated. However, if you are looking for an idea (based on just what you have shared) - I would suggest use jquery's each.

Comment: I can't share my code because it's  too big module. how i use each loop instead for of.

Comment: @HELP Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for-of` is not **supported on IE**. You can replace your **for-of-loop** with jquery's `each` as

```
$("[type=slideshow] section").addClass('hide');
$("[type=slideshow]").each( function(i,ele){ //i is the index and ele is the element in iteration
   $(ele).children("section:first").removeClass("hide").addClass('active');
});
```

Also, **no need to mix jquery with javascript's** `querySelector` and looping over results using for-loop.

When using # based selector `#slide` as in this line

```
var divSlide = document.querySelectorAll('#slide');
```

It is only going to give one result, simply use

```
timeline = $( "#slide" )[0];
```

No need for outer *for-loop* and *if-condition*.

Comment: Sure, Glad to help!